# Block screen recoding but allow HDMI screen mirroring Swift 4

Tags: ios, notifications, swift4, hdmi, screen-recording

I need to stop Screen recoding, however I need to allow video sharing through HDMI.

I know the captured notification is usually used for this, but I cant find a way to separate out these two things.

```
 UIScreen.main.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "captured", options: .new, context: nil)
```

The above triggers notifications when screen recording is started / stopped. But also triggers when an external display is connected / disconnected (though I'm finding it to be intermittent here).

I have tried using the following to detect if a screen within the UIScreen is mirrored or just to check the screen count. Recordings show only one screen in the count, and mirrored screens should show a count of 2

```
         recordingLabel.text = "count \(UIScreen.screens.count)"
            for screen in UIScreen.screens {
                if screen.mirrored != nil {
                    recordingLabel.text = "Mirrored - count \(UIScreen.screens.count)"
                }

            }
```

But again this is intermittent. Most of the time the count does not change on connecting a HDMI screen, but does change to 2 on disconnecting.

I have also found using UIScreen notifications work for connected / disconnected. But there seems to be a race condition happening with the captured notification that I still need to handle recordings.

```
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(connected), name: UIScreen.didConnectNotification, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(disconnected), name: UIScreen.didDisconnectNotification, object: nil)
```

Is there any way to detect the type of recording or prevent the race from happening when both types of notifications trigger?

EDIT :
 I have since found

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(captureChanged(notification:)), name: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Which works better with the connection notifications, but it still triggers before I get a connected notification. I don't really want to add a timer to detect if the didConnect notification triggers after the captureChange, but that might be the only way